# Can't find the first direct child element of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the code generating jQuery UI dialog from existing HTML template.

I want to extract title attribute from the HTML and use it as the title parameter for jQuery UI dialog method.

I tried `children().first(), find(">:first-child")`, etc but nothing worked.

titleStr is just undefined.

```
function define_Window() {
// constructor of class Window
MyNS.Window = function (path_html) {
    this.DIV = $("<div/>").load(path_html);
    var titleStr = this.DIV.children().first().attr("title");

    // To test if DIVs are well appended 
    this.DIV2 = $("<div/>").attr("name", "Form").load(path_html);
    $(MyNS.Windows).append(this.DIV2);

    this.DLG = this.DIV.dialog({
        title: titleStr
    });
```

Template HTML files look like this:

```
<div title="THIS IS TITLEEEEEE!!!!">
<p>Description goes here</p>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="">blahblahblah
```

Comment: You are getting the title from the first of the div's children. But there is no such attribute in your HTML except on the div itself. What's going on?

Comment: Try `$(this.DIV).children()(0).attr("title")`

Comment: this.DIV.children(':first').attr("title")

Comment: @Jon <div title="THIS IS TITLEE"> is DIV2's first child I checked it by Chrome Inspect element.

Comment: And what is DIV2 exactly? You should really tighten up this question and improve the description because frankly right now it's unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
var titleStr = "";
this.DIV = $("<div/>").load(path_html, function complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
     titleStr = $("div").first.attr("title");
} );
```

explanation: `load` gets the template through an asynchronous ajax request. therefore, the div alement carrying the title might not be available when you query for it in your code.

closure code adopts the call signature used by [the jquery api spec for `load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: This means that the line this.DLG = this.DIV.dialog({... also has to be inside the callback 'complete'. How could I refer 'this' (a Window object) from inside the callback function?

Comment: assign `this` to a variable outside the callback and use it from inside the closure.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you don't need Child, try this:

First you are selecting `this.DIV = $("div")`
So, This will return array of elements. You can select the first by using this:

```
var first_div = this.DIV.eq(0)
// Now you can select its title: 
first_div.attr('title');
```

Comment: Is $('<div/'>) same as $('div')? I used $('<div/>') to create a new DIV element.

Comment: You can't select `'<div/>'` but you can create it as `$("<div/>")`.. When you want to select an element, just call it without tags as `$("div")` or `$("body")`